# Create multiple tables through a "while" or procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a procedure to create multiple tables at once, either using a while or another command.

This is the database I have to create, but I was wondering if there was a faster way to do it through a loop:

[image: This is the database I have to create, but I was wondering if there was a faster way to do it through a loop]

The creation of column fields or fields in tables are the same. The problem arises when naming the tables created, since there are several.

```
declare @i int = 1
while (@i <= 11)
begin
    declare @nameoftable nvarchar(50)
    set @nameoftable ='dbo'+ '.' + 'tbl_' + convert(nvarchar, @i) + '000_Capitulo_100'
    print @nameoftable

    create table @nameoftable
    (
    cap100ID int primary key not null,
    ccdd int not null,
    ccpp int not null,
    ccdi int not null,
    tipoVia nvarchar(20) not null,
    nombVia nvarchar(50) not null
    )

    set @i = @i + 1
end;
```

This is the code that I advanced so far in sql server management.

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple tables with the same definition? Smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier and more flexible to include that `i` value in the table itself as a column (with a fitting name) and thus create only one table?

Comment: I also thought about it the first time. but they asked me that way. What happens is that this database is related to a social survey, which collects information on access to basic services, number of relatives, employment, income, etc. It is also divided by zones of a country.

Comment: Definitely looks like you have a design flaw. The number should be a column, not a part of the table's name. Then you only need 1 table, not *n+1* (where *n* is the number of tables you currently have)

Comment: If you do it like this, you will encounter the same problem when inserting, updating, deleting and querying data. You will basically have to do everything 11 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to agree with the comments regarding having multiple tables with identical structure and the possible problems it could cause but if you really need to do this you could use `EXEC`.

```
declare @i int = 1
while (@i <= 11)
begin

    declare @nameoftable nvarchar(50)
    declare @sqlCommand nvarchar(255)

    set @nameoftable ='dbo'+ '.' + 'tbl_' + convert(nvarchar, @i) + '000_Capitulo_100'

    SET @sqlCommand = 'create table ' + @nameoftable + 
                      '(cap100ID int primary key not null,
                        ccdd int not null,
                        ccpp int not null,
                        ccdi int not null,
                        tipoVia nvarchar(20) not null,
                        nombVia nvarchar(50) not null)'

    EXEC (@sqlCommand)

    set @i = @i + 1

end;
```

Comment: Note that you can replace `'dbo'+ '.' + 'tbl_'` with just `'dbo.tbl_'` as well. ;)

Comment: And if you want the `i` values smaller than 10 prefixed with a `0` (as shown in the OP's question's image), you could use `right('0' + convert(nvarchar, @i), 2)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

> not sure , this is what your are looking for?

```
EXEC('create table '+@nameoftable+'
(
cap100ID int primary key not null,
ccdd int not null,
ccpp int not null,
ccdi int not null,
tipoVia nvarchar(20) not null,
nombVia nvarchar(50) not null
)')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I did not know how to execute table creation including variables. And that was what he was looking for.